# Javascript Object Dragable? like Jquery Ui draggable function but in js ?

Tags: javascript

I want to make object get dragged like in Jquery because,i can't set max Coordinates that object can't go far for,if it is possible in jquery as well please Write Answers,Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [containment option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) to restrict draggability with jquery ui draggable.

Comment: Thank you bro,how can i move object only On y Or X verticses ?